# Upper bound for constant weight code L(n,d,w), with n=128, d=4

Tags: graph-theory, coding-theory, combinatorial-designs

I would like to find an upper bound:

L(n,d,w) <= f(n,d,w)

for a constant weight code L(n,d,w), where *w* is the maximum weight, *d* is the Hamming distance between codes, and *n* is the code length.  I have been directed to various resources for these upper bounds, for example:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.3657.pdf
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~venkatg/teaching/codingtheory/notes/notes4.pdf

but none of them apply to my case of n=128, d=4. Does anyone know of any upper bounds that apply to these extremely large *n*, small *d*, cases?